# Não consigo dar um grant em um schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Estou trabalhando com um banco SQL Server 2012 e estou tentando atribuir um grant a um schema com o seguinte comando:

```
GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA :: trunk TO trunk
```

E estou tendo o seguinte erro:

```
Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.
```

Alguém sabe como resolvo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No fundo o que ele te está a indicar é que estás a tentar dar permissões a um USER que ja tem essas permissões ou estás a correr o grant com o contexto do user que queres dar a permissão.

Ou seja tens de efectuar essa alteração com uma query a ser executada por um outro user com permissoes elevadas.